# Android "Handler" class missing in Intellij IDEA 13.1.4

Tags: android, intellij-idea, handler

I've recently moved from Eclipse + ADT to IntelliJ IDEA.
My current project is using:

Gradle 2.1 
JDK 1.7.0_67 
MinSdk 15 
TargetSdk 19

When I attempt to import the Android "Handler" class, it is simply not there. 
The only "Handler" I see there is the "java.util.logging" class, which is not what I need.

I have triple checked my project structure and that the appropriate API (19) is set as the project and module API level.

I'm obviously missing something here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the problem.

For some unexplained reason, that specific class, and that one only (android.os.Handler) was excluded in IntelliJ's Auto-Import settings under "IDE Settings" -> "Editor" -> "Auto Import"
When pressing CTRL-ALT-S for the general IDE settings.

Once I removed this exclusion, the class is again accessible to me.